# Open and Edit Excel sheet in browser and save it using Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, edit

Probably looking for a feasible solution for the below requirement

The user will upload the excel sheet through file upload in Web Application. And I am saving it in physical path of the server.For viewing it, I am rendering it in iframe in the html that works perfect.

Now the requirement is the entire excel sheet needs to be opened in browser and cells, rows, columns could be modified and then saved to server.

All with Interop, aspose, third party dlls, only certain fields could be edited through code by specifying the cell range and row number.

This case in quite that any cell/row/field value entire excel could be modified.

Comment: You can use Aspose.Cells.GridWeb to edit or modify any cell of a worksheet. Could you explain how do you want to modify entire Excel sheet at once. We will provide our feedback after analysis.
Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.